# Flow Type: How to create an instance of an exact type from a class

Tags: javascript, flowtype

I have the following type and class:

```
export type ProductType = {|
  id: number,
  name: string,
  slug: string,
  tooltip: string,
  properties?: string[]
|};

class Product {
  id: number,
  name: string,
  slug: string,
  tooltip: string,
  properties?: string[]

  constructor(props: $Shape<ProductType>) {
    this.id = props.id;
    this.name = props.name || '';
    this.slug = props.slug || '';
    this.tooltip = props.tooltip || '';
    this.properties = props.properties || [];
  }
}
```

and I'd like to be able to do something like this:

```
const product: ProductType = new Product({ name: 'test' });
```

but flows complain saying the following:

```
Cannot assign `new Product()` to `product` because inexact  `Product` [1] is incompatible with exact  `ProductType`
```

so I'd like to know if there is any way to return an exact/freeze/seal object from the class constructor or if this is even possible and if not what other alternatives I have.

Comment: Just a thought but do id, name, slug and tooltip all have to be mandatory in your ProductType. Could some or all be optional ?

Comment: @SimonLong yes they can optional but this is only an example and dont want to sound rude but dont see how this has anything to do with what I'm trying to do here

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, class instances are inexact. Here's an illustration:

```
class Foo {
  foo: string;
  constructor() {
    this.foo = 'foo';
  }
}

class Bar extends Foo {
  bar: string;
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.bar = 'bar';
  }
}

type JustFoo = {| foo: string |};

const x: Foo = new Bar();

// Expected error -- if Flow allowed this, the exact type would be a lie!
const y: JustFoo = x;

const z: JustFoo = { foo: "foo" };
```

([playground](https://flow.org/try/#0MYGwhgzhAEBiD29oG8BQ1oDNEC5oQBcAnASwDsBzAbnWmHjMKIFdgD4iAKAShVowIALEhAB02JAF5oAcgkyaGAL6oVqUJBgAhMEWgBTAB4F9ZACYwESNBgBGuvE3LVa9RsVbsuvGxnzMAB31vRT8hEVF7PWkZKIVaFTUCAE8g6AApZkIraGlkAB8sXHxiZ2h8pRp1BkJoQzwc6TJ9AHdoHRDUVAB6bugAUUMgtn0zAyIiDmgAWmnoEkw4EHg2sBBlltHocIgAGm3BfQNDMDZt1KOW+GYQMdsjsGgQEn0AQmr3aGS8TOzEXLqVTctQAXj8sgRGigivA8AAiCRw6CVIA))

In this case, `Bar` extends `Foo` and adds an additional property. Because classes are nominally typed, `Bar` is a subtype of `Foo`. Therefore, `Foo` cannot be a subtype of `{| foo: string |}` without breaking the type system.

The recommended way to create an exact object is to just write an object literal, like I did for `z` in this example.

Comment: thanks for your response and I understand class instances are inexact that's exactly the reason of my question to find out if there is a way to change that, I also know I can do something like this: `const product: ProductType = Object.freeze({ ...new Product({}) });` and it will work but I'd like to know if it's possible to do make a class instance return a exact type, I've tried a couple of different things like putting `Object.freeze(this)` at the end of the class ctor but apparently this is no possible :(

Comment: [playground](https://flow.org/try/#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) using the `Object.freeze`

Comment: It's probably a bug that Flow allows the combination of `Object.freeze` and spread to lead a copy of a class instance to be considered exact. If you really want to use classes, I recommend using inexact object types or just class instance types. If you really want to use exact types I recommend creating them with object literals.